# Image array and if statements for each frame Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, if-statement

I have been trying for a few days now to figure this out - I know it is something simple that I have probably missed but being new to iOS I think I missed something somewhere.

I have an array of image views in XCode and each image view is assigned a frame, what I cant seem to get to work is I want to compare each frame in each object from the array in an if else if statement sort of thing... I can't figure out how to make the system do something like this...

if frame in the array object at index 0 is (0,0) (90,90) then do something
or if it is (90,90) (90,90) do this instead
otherwise do this...

I know how the if else statements work - I guess my main question is how do I access the frame part of the object in the array for comparison?

I am confused. Please help. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you'll have to compare for each of the attributes in CGRect separately.

```
CGRect aRect = [[array objectAtIndex:0] frame];
if (aRect.origin.x == 0 && aRect.origin.y == 0 && aRect.size.width == 90 && aRect.size.height == 90){
    //do something
}
else if (aRect.origin.x == 90 && aRect.origin.y == 90 && aRect.size.width == 90 && aRect.size.height == 90){
    //do something else 
}
```

It could be that only the origin.x that you are concerned in your conditional statement, then you can simply to

```
CGRect aRect = [[array objectAtIndex:0] frame];
if (aRect.origin.x == 0){
    //do something
}
else if (aRect.origin.x == 90){
    //do something else 
}
```

Comment: OK cool - Thank you guys I will try these out. I really appreciate your help. I will post my results. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I saw the other answers but I think the OP wanted to know how to loop through the views array. 
So , here's the way to do that:

```
for(UIImageView *imgView in yourViewsArray)
{
   if([imgView isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
   {
       //insert IF statements here like the other answers showed.
   }
}
```

Comment: OK cool - Thank you guys I will try these out. I really appreciate your help. I will post my results. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CGRectContainsRect(CGRect rectReference, CGRect rectToCompareTo)` function.

It will return YES if the `rectToCompareTo` is inside `rectReference`.

You can find more similar functions here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

Comment: OK cool - Thank you guys I will try these out. I really appreciate your help. I will post my results. :)

Comment: You should also select one of these answers as an answer. People will be more likely to answer your questions in the future.